# Can't make messages with Django's JavascriptCatalogView

Tags: django, gettext, django-sites

I use Djnago with sites framework. The static root has the following structure:

- css
- js

  - site1.bundle.js
  - site2.bundle.js
  - site3.bundle.js

When I try to make messages (`python manage.py makemessages -d djangojs -a`) the command above extracts messages only from the `site1.bundle.js` and ignores other files.

How can I make single translation file from all JS files?